# Get request memory usage VM Azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine, metrics, azure-monitoring

I have virtual machine on azure I get the cpu usage, network in and network out from this link

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptions}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroups}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{virtualMachines}/providers/microsoft.insights/metrics?timespan=2018-10-22T03:00:00Z/2018-10-23T03:00:00Z&api-version=2018-01-01&metricnames=Percentage CPU,Network In,Network out
```

I want link that get Memory usage for this VM.
Any help?

Comment: I am not sure what you ask but take a look at this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-rest-api-walkthrough#retrieve-metric-definitions-multi-dimensional-api

Comment: I want jest get memory usage, I don't fine any resources  @Llazar

Answer (score 1):

In the azure portal select the VM that you need metrics for. Select Metrics from the sidebar menu and you will find the default metrics. For additional metrics you need to install the  Azure diagnostics agent.You can enable this from Diagnostics settings menu.Once you install it you can see multiple additional metrics are available for you to monitor. You can select whichever metric you want and save. You can also create alerts for specific metrics.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management/azure-vm-extended-metrics

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/alert-metric-classic

Comment: Thank You, but i need to get memory usage using rest api]

Comment: once the metric you required has been configured you can access it via REST API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics#getmetric

Comment: @Aravind I have installed the Azure Diagnostics agent, and I have used the following API but it doesn't return the metrics data, Any hint? [link](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTION>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/<RESOURCE>/providers/microsoft.insights/metrics?metricnamespace=azure.vm.linux.guestmetrics&api-version=2018-01-01&metricnames=/builtin/memory/usedmemory&timespan=2019-01-20T00:00:00Z/2019-01-30T00:00:00Z&interval=PT5M)

Comment: @AhmedRezk the error says subscription is incorrect. Are you querying the right subscription after successfully logging into that subscription??

Comment: @Aravind I finally got my hands on the cause. I needed to configure a "data sinks" to route metrics to the Azure Monitor metrics store so that it can be collected with the metrics API; according to this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/collect-custom-metrics-guestos-resource-manager-vm

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, memory usage is guest OS metrics. You should enable guest-level monitoring on Diagnostics settings blade of Virtual Machine Agent. For more detail, you can refer to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management/azure-vm-extended-metrics). Besides, memory usage is only available within the guest-level VM, not from host OS so it won't be available via the metrics API. I'm afraid there is no REST API today to retrieve the memory metrics. Hope it will be helpful!